# Angular route segments with missing parent: how to avoid errors?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular14

I have an `Angular 14` app that uses the routing module, and I have a couple of routes that look like this:

```
{path: "settings/global", component: GlobalSettingsEditComponent, ...},
{path: "settings/tenant", component: TenantSettingsEditComponent, ...},
{path: "settings/license", component: LicensePageComponent, ...}
```

However, I do not have any route mapped to the `"settings"` path, so these paths are "parentless" in a sense. This is ok, since I do not have a generic "settings" page in this app, all the sections of the settings are accessed directly via a menu.

Now, functionally this configuration seems to work without issues and when navigating to those paths the associated components load correctly. However, every time I navigate to one of those paths I get this error on the browser's console:

> Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'settings'

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue so I'm guessing: Have you tried smth like `{path: "settings", redirectTo: "settings/global"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happen because Angular didn't see such a route in your config. To avoid this you can use the following structure. Notice that `component` is optional for the route so you can avoid it.

```
  {
    path: 'settings',
    children: [
      { path: "global", component: GlobalSettingsEditComponent, ...},
      { path: "tenant", component: TenantSettingsEditComponent, ...},
      { path: "license", component: LicensePageComponent, ...}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but it has a weird problem: now when I go to one of the sub-url, like  `settings/global`, I get immediately redirected to the base `settings` path (which displays nothing because it doesn't have an associated component). Why is this happening?

Comment: @Master_T I created the demo to check it and this is works, please take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-kgu6tm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.routing.ts

Maybe you have some redirects inside your routing config? Can you show the full config in stackblitz or here?

Comment: I've accepted your answer, as it is the correct implementation. The redirect problem was unrelated (it was an issue in my nav menu that was triggering navigation on both the child and parent link one after the other)